# Use xml format file to edit csv before bulk insert into ms sql

Tags: sql-server, bulk-load

SQL :Bulk insert

```
bulk insert TESTING
    from 'D:\Testing.csv'
    with
( FIRSTROW=2,
     DATAFILETYPE='char',
      FIELDTERMINATOR=',',

      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      FORMATFILE = 'D:\Testing.xml');
```

XML : Format file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
 <FIELD ID="Address1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
 <FIELD ID="Address2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
 <FIELD ID="Address3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
 <FIELD ID="Address4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\n' />
</RECORD>
 <ROW>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="Address1" NAME="COLUMN1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
 <COLUMN SOURCE="Address2" NAME="COLUMN2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
 <COLUMN SOURCE="Address3" NAME="COLUMN3" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
 <COLUMN SOURCE="Address4" NAME="COLUMN4" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

The csv file that I have used contain address. I have created a SQL table before bulk insert. There are four column for address.

Testing.csv

"Address1","Address2","Address3","Address4"
"Lot 180, Street 19, "," Oakland Park, "," Kuala Lumpur, "," Selangor"

[image]

I want to get the output like in the table above. When i try use the xml format file in bulk insert, I received following error message:

```
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK"
for linked server "(null)".
```